# Difference between GTK in ubuntu 14.04 and 16.04

Tags: 14.04, unity, gtk

I am new to Ubuntu, and currently I have Ubuntu 14.04 with Unity installed, but one of the things that bother is lack of thumbnails in image picker(example: while uploading images on imgur), I know this is a bug/design choice in Gtk and that Gtk 3 doesn't have this problem which 16.04 uses(?), so when I update to Ubuntu 16.04 will this fix itself? Looking around about Gtk I found that I don't need to install anything and that I just need to compile apps with Gtk2/3, now being new I'd rather not mess around with that so:

1. Can I fix this issue with 14.04 Unity install?
2. Does 16.04 have this problem?